# Connecting to dockerized MySQL database on Laravel App

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

For the first time I wanted to use Docker for my Laravel project and I just created the app with newest Laravel 8. I'm using Laravel Sail for starting the Docker. For now, thing goes pretty well, but I don't know how to connect on MySQL database.

When I start docker with command "sail up", after that how can I make connection on MySQL database with Navicat for example, or even on phpmyadmin?

This is .env content for MySQL:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_example
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: Inside Laravel, you should be using `DB_HOST=mysql`, and outside use `127.0.0.1:3306`.

Comment: Or you can find an ip used by docker container with `docker exec container-name hostname -I` where container-name is MySQL docker container name. Which can be found using `docker container ls`. Works on linux. Should work in any OS.

Answer (score 2):

To connect to **MySQL** that is in the **Docker container** you need to use your machine's IP.

If you are in a MacOS you can get the IP using the following command:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set DB_HOST=mysql_container_name

Also, you can create phpmyadmin container, add container to the same network and connect with mysql DB, like i did in my docker-compose file:

```
 ...
phpmyadmin:
            container_name: phpmyadmin
            image: phpmyadmin
            environment:
              PMA_HOST: db-mysql (your mysql-container name)
              PMA_USER: phpmyadmin
              PMA_PASSWORD: PASS
            ports:
              - 8080:80
            depends_on:
              - db-mysql (your mysql-container name)
            networks:
              - backend (here is common network)
 ...
```